# SQL: Return two max dates from two columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to return two max dates from two different columns within the same table. I want the result to be in the same line.
This is my table data:

```
If i have this          
store   item    tran-code   date
1788    2004635    1      17.05.27
1788    2004635    2      17.05.27
1788    2004635   30      17.05.26
1788    2004635    2      17.05.21
1788    2004635    1      17.05.21
1788    2004635    2      17.05.20
1788    2004635    1      17.05.20
```

and i want this…

```
store   item    tran-code   date
1788    2004635    1      17.05.27
1788    2004635    30     17.05.26
```

but if you could get me to return this, it will be perfect

```
store   item      date_1    date_30
1788    2004635  17.05.27   17.05.26
```

where date_1 is the max date for tran-code = 1 and 
date_30 is the max date for tran-code = 30

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the answer you want. And you have two lines in your result so it kinda contradicts the second part of your question.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle or SQLServer

Answer (score 1):

Just use `group by`

```
select store,item,
 max(sales_date) as sales_date ,
 max(purchase_date) as purchase_date 
from your_table
group by store,item;
```

[Rextester Demo for SQL Sever](http://rextester.com/GIJX12913) but this is a generic query and will work on all RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table 
WHERE sales_date = MAX(sales_date) 
OR purchase_date = MAX(purchase_date) 
ORDER BY MAX(sales_date), MAX(purhcase_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Keepeing two dates in seperate columns is fine.Just use this:

```
select concat(max(sales_date), '  ',max(purchase_date)) as newColumn
```

Notice how I added space between two dates.

Comment: This is not at all what OP wants.

Comment: I forgot to put Max before colums.Let me edit and It would do the trick